# How can I make a best-sellers list?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a "best sellers" list using information from previous orders. What I currently have is something like this;

```
Product Quantity
2227    30
1722    3
1851    7
2227    10
1722    4
1863    1
etc....
```

The first column (product) is the unique ID in the database for each product. The quantity is of course how many items have been sold. Each row is for one order. So the ID `2227` appears two times on this list.

How can I sort this data so that I get a total of how many times ID `2227` is sold?

My PHP at the moment is:

```
$SQL_best = "SELECT c.company, co.id, cod.productId, cod.quantity 
FROM customers c 
LEFT JOIN customers_orders co ON c.id = co.custId 
LEFT JOIN customers_orders_details cod ON co.id = cod.orderId 
WHERE c.reseller =1 
AND c.status != 99 
AND c.id = ".$intCustomerId; 

$result_best = $objDB->sqlExecute($SQL_best);

*some html code here*

<table style="margin:0px auto;">
<tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($obj_best = $objDB->getObject($result_best)) {
    if ($obj_best->quantity > 0) { // don't include negatve quantaties (RMA's / refunds)
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$obj_best->productId."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$obj_best->quantity."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

MySQL query

So I need to add together all the `$obj_best->productId`´s. How do I do that in this case? Or should I be editing my query?

Comment: Add a `SUM(cod.quantity)` to your select list; then order desc by that column.... filter out negative quantities in your SQL query, not in PHP

Comment: You should change your query.  You need the aggregate function SUM with a GROUP BY clause on your product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an idea, you change the SQL string like this:

```
$SQL_best = "SELECT c.company, co.id, cod.productId,
SUM(cod.quantity) AS quantity
FROM customers c 
LEFT JOIN customers_orders co ON c.id = co.custId 
LEFT JOIN customers_orders_details cod ON co.id = cod.orderId 
WHERE c.reseller = 1 
AND c.status != 99 
AND c.id = " . $intCustomerId . "
GROUP BY cod.productId
HAVING quantity > 0
ORDER BY quantity DESC";
```